# Python code for controlling multiple mouse cursors on my screen at once

Tags: python-3.x

Is there any python code for controlling multiple mouse cursors on my screen at once on single computer?

Comment: How do you get multiple cursors on the screen?

Comment: @IvailoBardarov , see this https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/using-two-cursors-in-windows/c3957da1-99ec-435d-b5a1-7e144f360a2a#:~:text=Unfortunately%2C%20Windows%20does%20not%20enable,some%20time%20to%20consider%20first.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I wish to make a python code through which I can control my two mouse simultaneously on one desktop. One for normal operation( like a usual mouse) and the other one for just scrolling purpose. Is it possible to make a just controlling function in Python. if yes how can I do it?

Comment: Exactly @faraazkurawle one like this pluralinput https://pluralinput.com/index-old.html but this one is paid I want to make my own code for this one. So that I do not have to pay for it.

Comment: @ZainabZzzz , i got it, you want a code which would add another cursor on screen, not to control multiple cursor with python. I guess you will control it by another mouse?

Comment: @ZainabZzzz , check this out https://mousemux.com/

Comment: Yes I also have found this MouseMux but what I  want to know is isn't there any method through which I could do the same but by through python coding.

Comment: Cursors are very coupled to the operating system. You have to specify your OS name and the windows manager  that you use. This is not only a python question. 
It is still not clear the method that you used to show multiple cursors on your screen have you used proprietary drivers?